# Using multiple random seeds to keep agents and environment separate

Tags: netlogo

I have a simulation which proceeds in two general flows, (1) the environment changes, and (2) the agents do their thing.

I've carefully designed this so that the environment and agent behavior are fully independent. This is important because I want to be able to simulate an experiment in which the environment evolves in a repeated pattern across runs, but the agent variables change.

I know that I can run the environment using "with-local-randomness", but that only works if I can maintain two random seeds across time. I don't see an obvious way of doing this.

One idea I considered is to initialize the environment with a list "environment-seeds" which would be a list of 1000 new-seeds, then each time I call with-local-randomness get the next seed off the list (hoping that I don't eventually run out by accident). Unfortunately I don't have any idea for how to keep the list across runs, other than hard-coding it.

tl;dr I need two have two random number generators, based on different seeds, and I need to be able to switch which one is being used for any given call in the code.

Thanks a lot for any ideas!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing exactly what you want is impossible unless you write an [extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API) that gives you more control over the RNG state than is offered by the primitives built in to NetLogo. (To see how saving and restoring RNG state looks, you could look at the code that `export-world` and `import-world` use to do it.)

But I think your `environment-seeds` idea is a good workaround. You could store the seeds in a file and use `file-read` to pull them out. Or, you could generate them on the fly using a separate RNG, as provided by Adam MacKenzie's RNG extension, listed at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions ; then you wouldn't have to worry about running out. There might be a clever way of generating each seed as a function of the previous seed without involving that extension, actually. How about making the next seed be the first number generated by the RNG after being initialized (inside `with-local-randomness` of course) with the previous seed?

Comment: All very helpful, but that last idea is golden! That solves the whole thing :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want a random environment: You want a repeatable environment that happens to have been randomly generated.

So, I would suggest you first write your environment simulation, run it for the maximim required number of steps, while recording for each step the state of the environment (in a format and using a method that you devise).

Then, for your actual experiment, you run your agent simulation over the playback of the recorded environment (using a method you devise).

Note, however, that every time you use ASK (such as "ask patches [ update-from-recorded-values ]) you are using the random number generator, and that will affect your agents random stream--but it sounds like that would be OK.

If you can accept that (assuming that gives you what you want in terms of "repeatabilty"), well, there you go.